# S6 oneshot script, if: fatal: unterminated block

Tags: if-statement, s6

I'm using S6 v3 with a working configuration until the latest addition, which I'm stuck with.

I'm trying to check whether an env. variable is certain value, so I can execute a command.

Here's what I have:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/with-contenv sh

if [["dev" = "$APP_ENV"]]; then\
    exec printf '#################################################################';\
fi
```

I've tried various variations, including the use of `test` function.
No solutions to be found online.

I assume it's a silly issue. Please let me know what is the issue and where I can learn more about the syntax used with S6 executables (the script above runs as expected in host machine with `#!/usr/bin/env sh`)

Answer (score 1):

After some research on the topic I've found that (according to s6 documentation) the up and down files are special: they're not shell scripts, but single command lines interpreted by [execlineb](https://skarnet.org/software/execline/). That means that an `up` file contains a single command line. So in my case, having a script with several instructions, here's how I solved the issue:

- Created an **executable** file mounted in `/etc/s6-overlay/scripts/my_script` (the location is arbitrary)
- Call that script in the `up` file, with env. vars (because I need them) like this:

```bash
with-contenv
/etc/s6-overlay/scripts/my_script
```

Also, maybe it is worth mentioning that `pwd` is not the `WORKDIR` that is defined in the container, so if you relay on that, then you need to `cd` first.